# xfce launcher problems with java programs

Tags: xfce, 15.10

I'm having a bit of strangeness with all forms of the launcher (desktop and panel) when it comes to java programs. I add for example IntelliJ Idea from the whisker menu to a panel and it has the following command:
"/home/xxx/local/idea-IC-143.381.42/bin/idea.sh" %f

I can take this command and execute it in a terminal and it works fine. But when I press the launcher button a window never shows up. I can see a process that is running that does hog some resources.

I did the same thing with SQLWorkbench (with a manually created) desktop launcher with the following as the command:

/home/dave/local/sqlworkbench/sqlworkbench.sh

In this case when I start it an upstart process starts that hogs around 99% CPU.

All other launchers are working. I'm pretty sure the above were working too but am not 100% sure (as the install is less than a month old).

I'm on 15.10 and installed all updates (including some prompted ones today).

Any one having this and has a fix?

Answer (score 0):

It will be because the startup scripts are looking for a JDK_HOME environment variable, and none is present.

You can edit the startup scripts to set the JDK_HOME at the start of the scripts, or edit the /etc/profile file to set it (then log out and log in).